# Adding SOAP Headers to Request (wsdl2objc client)

Tags: ios, soap-client

I'm using a client generated by wsdl2objc successfully, but the service it consumes will soon be changed to require a user identifying string in the SOAP header.

The closest thing I can find is in the client code's `main` function:

```
NSMutableDictionary *headerElements = nil;
headerElements = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

I'm okay with hard-coding a header here, because I don't expect my user key to change, but how is it *supposed* to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem here. Interesting thread [here](http://groups.google.com/group/wsdl2objc-discuss/browse_thread/thread/22a85a2ee563ad0c/cb835758ef29b896?q=%2522Igor%2bIstochnick%2522#cb835758ef29b896&ei=iGwTS6eaOpW8Qpmqic0O&sa=t&ct=res&cd=1&source=groups&usg=AFQjCNFdWXPjYYIAFUr92te9HeG2NZ3ADg) where a user suggests that :

Actually if your wsdl properly supports wsse:Security, then the whole
framework should work as-is. 
Your wsdl should refer to this xsd: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext/secext.xsd 
and should state for each operation that uses wsse:Security, that it
takes as input a Security header object.